# ZedGraph Not Found GraphPane.YAxisList Method

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I want to draw 3 Y Axis my GraphPane. I saw the examples. Examples are saying below;

```
YAxis yAxis3 = new YAxis( "Distance, m" );
myPane.YAxisList.Add( yAxis3 );
```

But myPane does not has YAxisList method. You can see the screenshot below;

[image: You can see my code]

Comment: The code you posted [works perfectly well](https://imgur.com/deJsHd3). The problem must be somewhere else. Try things like open/close project, clean/re-build, etc. `ZedGraph ` v2.0.50727 compiled from source code.

Comment: Can you give me a link for v2.0.507727 @jsanalytics

Comment: Download the `master` branch: https://github.com/ZedGraph/ZedGraph

Comment: i will try and write here conclusion. @jsanalytics

Comment: You could try adding ZedGraph via the NuGet package manager

Comment: @GodLovesATrier thank you. NuGet fix my problem.